# Using scanf with a while loop to input two separate strings

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I'm trying to make a program which reads in a name and number which is separated with a space and allocates the input to a structure.

```
typedef struct {

    char name [20];
    char number [12];
} Entry;
```

The `scanf` function is in a while loop, and I'd like it to break from the while loop if the input is `"."`

```
while(strcmp(e.name,".")!=0) {
    scanf("%s %s", e.name, e.number );
}
```

But using the above code means that the user has to input two periods. I was wondering if anybody had any advice on how I could make it break from the loop after the first `"."`.

Comment: What if someone inputs `"this_name_is_longer_than_twenty_characters 12345678901234567890"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two conditions:

```
while(1) {  //infinite loop

    scanf("%19s", e.name);
    getchar(); //remove the \n from the stdin
    if(strcmp(e.name,".")==0)
        break;

    scanf("%11s", e.number);
    getchar(); //remove the \n from the stdin
    if(strcmp(e.number,".")==0)
        break;
}
```

The 19 and 11 tells `scanf` to scan a maximum of that much characters and then,append a `\0` at the end.

Comment: Does the use of "%19s" and "%11s" make it completely safe to use scanf?

Comment: Those makes `scanf` more safer by preventing buffer overflows

Comment: `"%*s"` 1) reads and discards optional white-space then 2) reads discards non-white space until 3) it reads a white-space, which is then put back into `stdin`.   The following comment "remove the \n from the stdin" is then confusing.  If you want to use `scanf()` to remove a `'\n'`, code could use `scanf("%*1[\n]")`.  IAC, good to use `"19s"`, `"11s"`, but prefer `fgets()/sscanf()`

Comment: @chux , Oops.Forgot that `scanf` will not read newlines and spaces when used that way. I've used `getchar()` there.Wouldn't that work the same way as `scanf("%*1[\n]")`?

Comment: Of course `getchar()` will consume the next `char`, whatever it is, be it a `'\n'` or whatever.  Good enough for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend, replace your `scanf()` with `fgets()`. Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for the syantax.

1. Read the input [yes, a sinle line input, separated with a space]
2. tokenize and validate the input
3. do the processing.

This way, comparing the input with a `.` (in case of exit condition) will do the job.

<sup>Don't forget to take care of the trailing `\n` which will be read and stored into buffer by `fgets()`</sup>

Comment: @KlasLindbäck ,  @ CoolGuy Right Sir !! my bad. Corrected.

Comment: Would this require the use of strtok() aswell?

Comment: @ElisJones Right you are. Give it a try.